# Problem to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

In the Update manager, 12.04 was available. I started the download (700m aprox), but my internet connection crashed and i couldn't complete the dowload (remainde 100m aprox.). The downloads until this point were installed, but my system didn't upgrade to 12.04, it remained in 11.10. The problem is, the 12.04 update doesn't show in the Update manager. How can i upgrade? Can i undo the (partial) installation done? Thanks in advance, i'm novice using linux/ubuntu

Comment: Would you please run the command `head -20 /etc/apt/sources.list` in a terminal window. Then edit/update your question and use copy & paste to add the output from the command to your question. [*Please do **not** use a comment. Add the output to your question*](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the update to continue then you might want to try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

the last command should continue the installation process

If you see any issues, run this

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```